# Autohotkey - Send default behavior if condition not met

Tags: autohotkey

In Autohotkey, how can I make NumpadDot double-click if Foxit Reader is active, otherwise send a normal NumpadDot?

My (broken) attempt:

```
NumpadDot::
  SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; allow partial titles
  IfWinActive, Foxit
      Click 2
  else
      Send {NumpadDot} ; THIS CREATES AN ENDLESS LOOP!
Return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would do it this way:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; allow partial titles

#IfWinActive, Foxit ; Any hotkeys defined between #IfWInActive ONLY works in Foxit
  NumpadDot::Click 2
#IfWinActive
```

Oh btw the endless loop is because your Send, {NumPadDot} initiates your own script. If you want to prevent that place a $ before the hotkey like this $NumpadDot::

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! I had avoided this approach, perhaps wrongly, because of performance reasons: each key pressed must evaluate if Foxit is active, as opposed to first evaluating which key was pressed.

Comment: I made a small edit to clarify that only hotkeys are affected by `#IfWinActive`.  Other code will still run, with no effect.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend @RobertIlbrink's answer, but here's another way to do it.

```
$NumpadDot::
IfWinActive, Foxit
    Click 2
else
    SendInput {NumpadDot}
return
```

The `$` prevents AutoHotkey from confusing sent keystrokes (via Send commands) with keypresses made by the user.  If we didn't put that, we would get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I Have solved it through "SendPlay", in this example i have 2 keyboards, so i  use {tab} from keyboard1 to do {RAlt}{TAb} to Windows and I use {tab} from the main keyboard to do the usual stuff

```
Tab::
  getKeyboardID()               ; AHKHID based routine
  if(kbID = keyboard1){
    send, {Ralt Down}{Tab}{RAlt Up}
  } Else {
   SendPlay {Tab}               ; here the solution
  }
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have the else statement:

```
 NumpadDot::
     SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; allow partial titles
     IfWinActive, Foxit
 Click 2

return
```

Comment: when I copy and paste this to Autohotkey and reload the script, then go to Notepad and press the period on the numeric keypad, no period appears. How can I make the period appear?